# storing data in device after the first time they are recalled android

Tags: android, storage

I want to do this. my app has many screens and in each of them, on the top, I display an imageView as a logo. So I have 20 screens and that means (20*3) images in my drawable which makes my app be many Mb's. Because this image is static and never changes I want to do this: Getting it from the web (I know how to do it, I am not asking this) only for the first time this screen is ever launched, then this image be stored somewhere in user's device and then use that path as a source. (I mean not download it again, because it will be annoying for the user waiting every time). So is it possible? Will it make my app go slower (not the first time, but the rest) because I am retrieving data from SD?

Comment: So you have 60 different images? Or is there only 1 static image that you show in 60 places?

Comment: 20 logos, each one for each screen.

Comment: Why not making a Layout containing your header or logo and then use <include> in each layout that needs to show it(One image for any number of screens) , with http download you have to deal with offline users , data usage

Comment: each screen has its own logo. So I will have 20 logos. Because each logo is stored in 3 different drawables (hdpi and so on), I have 60 images, which make my size goes up. I want to reduce my app size, so I prefer the tradeoff: download it the first time, save it somewhere, and then bring it every next time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this fairly easily. You also do not have to store the data on the SD card necessarily. You can store the image in the internal storage.

Basically, set up a cache directory. When you need the image, check the cache directory, and if the file is not there, download it over http and store the file in the cache directory.

It will change how you get the resource (e.g., you won't be able to use R.drawable.imagename), but you can just load the drawable programmatically.

Comment: is there any sample code on how to set up a cache in android?

Comment: By cache, I just mean files on the file system. I'm not envisioning anything more complex than whats in the Data Storage section of the Android reference docs (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)